Method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::isDoctrineAvailable does not exist
Method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::isDoctrineAvailable does not exist.
i need someone help me these issue I have made a backup of my specific tables that I want to restore into a new database using: call pg_dump -Fc -h server -d database -U user -p password -v -f dump.sql -t public.table1 -t public.table2 And I have no problems. I then want to restore the dump by creating a new ...

laravel 11 is no longer dependent on doctrine/dbal.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
